# How to change text in textbox

Tags: javascript

Ok this is wheat I have so far. IF someone could help me out. I had to change the color of the background when you click on a button. And I also have to Use document.getElementById('yourelementid') to both find the value of the textarea and to change the basic text created in the div. But I don't know how to do that i have been researching online. I think i am getting a little confused about where to put things at in here thanks.

Here is what I have so far....

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD Xhtml 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http:www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <title>DOM</title>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <script language="JavaScript">
     <!-- Begin
       function newbg(thecolor)
      {
     document.bgColor=thecolor;
      }

     //  End -->
     </script>
      <body>
    <h3>DOM Assignment Examples</h3>
     <div>
    <form>
      <h4>Change background color to:</h4>
     <input type="radio" value="White" onclick="newbg('white');">white<br/>
     <input type="radio" value="Blue" onclick="newbg('blue');">Blue<br />
     <input type="radio" value="Beige" onclick="newbg('Beige');">Beige<br />
     <input type="radio" value="Yellow" onclick="newbg('yellow');">Yellow<br />
    </form>
   </div>
   <br />
    <br />
    <br />
     <h4>add text to this box change the text below:</h4>
    <TEXTAREA NAME="" ROWS="10" COLS="40" onBlur="blurHandlerRouting">
    You will change this text
  </TEXTAREA> <br />
  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="testResults(this.form)">
   </body>


  </html>
```

Comment: I don't understand... when the user clicks on the button, what happens? The contents of the `<textarea>` are transferred to... what?

Comment: I am suppose to Create a div with some basic text to start out.  Create a form that has a textarea.  Use document.getElementById('yourelementid') to both find the value of the textarea and to change the basic text created in the div. (Hint: user innerHTML)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The contents of a `<textarea>` can be manipulated using `.html()` in jQuery or `.innerHTML` in vanilla JavaScript.

Your HTML should contain the `id=""` attribute:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea">Text to be changed</textarea>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('mytextarea').innerHTML = "New Text";
```

Comment: Yeah he said i had to use .innerHTML I am just still a little confused about that part.

Comment: .value is more reliable than .innerHTML.

Answer (score 7):

To change the background and the textarea you would try this:

```
function = testResults(){
    document.getElementById("yourTextBoxId").style="background:red;"; //Change the background color to red.
    document.getElementById("yourTextAreaId").value="your another text for the textarea"
}
```

Comment: .value is more reliable than .innerHTML.